# Mapping of JSON attributes to integers using Spring Java

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a lot of JSON files in the following format. I want to map one attribute named **Timings** to **integer**.

**test.json**

```
"Rating": {
  "ratingValue": "4.636365",
  "bestRating": "5",
  "worstRating": "1",
  "ratingCount": "66"
 },
 "Timings": {
  "cookTime": "PT1H",
  "prepTime": "PT10M",
  "totalTime": "PT1H10M"
 }
```

I want to store the output in another JSON file after mapping. Let say, **totalTime** in **Timings** is **1H10M** then we assign this as "**totalTime:7**".  If its, "**30M**" we can assign this as "**totalTime:3**". I want to do this using java.

**Required output**

```
"Rating": 
{
  "ratingValue": "4.636365",
},
 "Timings": 
{
    "totalTime": "7"
}
```

Comment: Will the json contain timing data in second also ? for example : `"PT1H10M20S"`

Comment: @AnishB. No. Just Hour and Minutes

Comment: Ok fine. Working on the solution.

Comment: @AnishB thanks . I also need to store the output in JSON.

Comment: How your output json will look like ? Can you provide an example.

Comment: @AnishB. check the updated Qs. I have written in Qs.

Comment: How the data will come ? For example : for `30M` -> total time -> 3, then, for `11M`, then what the output you want ? Do you want the output to be in mins ?

Comment: @AnishB. I want to set a lookup table in which I right the ranges of values which map with the integers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210118/discussion-between-lily-and-anish-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this :

```
class Timings {

    private String cookTime;
    private String prepTime;
    private String totalTime;

    public String getCookTime() {
        return cookTime;
    }

    public void setCookTime(String cookTime) {
        this.cookTime = cookTime;
    }

    public String getPrepTime() {
        return prepTime;
    }

    public void setPrepTime(String prepTime) {
        this.prepTime = prepTime;
    }

    public String getTotalTime() {
        return totalTime;
    }

    public void setTotalTime(String totalTime) {
        this.totalTime = totalTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Timings [cookTime=" + cookTime + ", prepTime=" + prepTime + ", totalTime=" + totalTime + "]";
    }

}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Timings obj = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\Users\\Anish\\Desktop\\abc.json"), Timings.class);
        String totalTime = obj.getTotalTime().split("PT")[1];
        int total = 0;
        if (totalTime != null && !totalTime.isEmpty()) {
            total = returnTotalTime(totalTime);
        }
        ObjectNode mainNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        ObjectNode timingNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        childNode.put("totalTime", (total > 9) ? (total / 10) : total);
        mainNode.set("Timings", timingNode);
        String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mainNode);
        System.out.println(json);

    }

    private static int returnTotalTime(String totalTime) {
    if (totalTime != null && !totalTime.isEmpty()) {
        String[] timeValues = totalTime.split("H");
        if (timeValues.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (timeValues.length < 2) {
            if (timeValues[0].contains("M")) {
                return (timeValues[0].split("M").length <= 0) ? 0
                        : timeValues[0].split("M")[0].isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(timeValues[0].split("M")[0]);
            }
            return timeValues[0].isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(timeValues[0]) * 60;
        }
        int hour = timeValues[0].isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(timeValues[0]) * 60;
        int mins = (timeValues[1].split("M").length <= 0) ? 0
                : timeValues[1].split("M")[0].isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(timeValues[1].split("M")[0]);
        return (hour + mins);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

abc.json

```
{
  "cookTime": "PT1H",
  "prepTime": "PT10M",
  "totalTime": "PT1H10M"
}
```

Output :

```
{
  "Timings" : {
    "totalTime" : "7"
  }
}
```

When `"totalTime": "PT30M"`, then :

Output :

```
{
  "Timings" : {
    "totalTime" : "3"
  }
}
```

When `"totalTime": "PT23M"`, then :

Output :

```
{
  "Timings" : {
    "totalTime" : "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I want a little bit of improvement in this.

Whenever I am passing the exact multiple of 10 it is returning the required answer. But when ever I type ` "totalTime": "PT23M" ` it is returning back answer ` "totalTime" : "23" ` instead of ` "totalTime" : "3" `.   Please figure out this.

Comment: No sir. This is the problem. I don't need `23`. I need it to be `2`. Like for `PT37M` I need `3`.

Comment: @Lily Done. Now, check the updated answer. I have changed the code. It will work for any combination.

Comment: this code is giving error when `"totalTIme":"PT1H"`  
` java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Comment: @Lily Wait looking.

Comment: @Lily I have updated the code. I checked for max worst cases for data. Now, if some other cases are missing, plz add those by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any library to parse Json data depending of your goals.

for example org.json is a good choice and here is an example:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(stringData);
String time = object.getJSONObject("Timings").getString("cookTime");
```

this way you can parse every Json data and do your business after that.

Also you can use mapping your data to a class with gson or other tools.

Comment: How to map it to an Integer?

Comment: Where to make the lookup to map it to integer values?

Comment: as getString method, it has getInt method, too. but all properties in the json data you have mentioned are String.

Comment: Sir, I could access the object by this method. But I also want to map it after comparing it with a lookup.

Comment: what is the `stringData` ? Does it mean the path to read the JSON file?
I